# Kafka offset management with exception handling

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I was thinking of using hybrid pattern for offset management is to combine commitAsync() with commitSync() just before shutdown.
I saw this code but i did not under stand one part here
Suppose we get 100 record from poll and started processing the record asynchronously if exception occurs we will not know for which offset committing exception occurred by the time.

when it will go to finally try block. I am confused here

```
try {
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.printf("topic = %s, partition = %s, offset = %d,
                customer = %s, country = %s\n",
                record.topic(), record.partition(),
                record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
        consumer.commitAsync(); 
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Unexpected error", e);
} finally {
    try {
        consumer.commitSync(); 
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not a safe pattern if you care about data integrity.

Comment: @kayaman here my issue when it will go to finally try block. Using this are we able to  save in the middle of processing ? Here I guess we will be saving the latest offest only not in the middle

Comment: _will not know for which offset_... That is what [`OffsetCommitCallback` parameter is for](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync-org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback-). CommitAsync does not throw exceptions or block, and these need to be caught in the callback

Comment: Ugh, this isn't even an idempotency issue. You're subject to *losing* up to 100 records from being processed if an exception occurs, due to the unconditional commit in the finally block. Not safe at all.

Comment: @Kayaman According to the docs, all `commitAsync` calls are guaranteed to finish before futher `commitSync`. And the print statement is all the "processing" being done. So, where is data lost?

Comment: @OneCricketeer due to the "I saw this code" part in the question, I'm assuming the actual code will involve something more complex than just printing out records.